# Run fabfile with crontab

Tags: python, cron, fabric

I'm struggling with running fabfile by crontab.

My crontab file after running `crontab -l`:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/myproject/schedule.sh
*/2 * * * * env > /home/myproject/logs.txt
```

My `schedule.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/local/bin/fab --fabfile /home/myproject/fabfile.py run
```

This is what crontab logs show after command `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`:

```
Feb 14 14:32:01 VM CRON[10404]: (Beorn) CMD (/home/myproject/schedule.sh)
Feb 14 14:32:01 VM CRON[10405]: (Beorn) CMD (env > /home/myproject/logs.txt)
```

The content of logs.txt:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/home/project
LANG=en_NG
HOME=/home/project
LANGUAGE=en_NG:en

LOGNAME=project
_=/usr/bin/env
```

The result of `echo $PATH` inside of `/home/myproject` folder:

```
PATH = /home/project/bin:/home/project/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I read some stuff about this already but I can't make it work. I tried to change PATH but I'm not even sure if I'm doing it correctly. Logs saving is working as expected but fabfile is not running ...

Comment: is `/home/project` and `/home/myproject` supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: no they are diffrent

Comment: Does the file work if it's no in cron? i.e. if you run it manually does it work?

Comment: "/usr/local/bin/fab --fabfile /home/myproject/fabfile.py run" manually works fine

Comment: Have you tried that as the cron job? 1) if you run the bash script manually does it work? And 2) is there a reason you are using the bash script instead of running the working command in cron directly?

Comment: 1) Yes schedule.sh works manually. 2) Not really just tried to do same thing as people in other posts.

Comment: For all your crontab problems: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 0):

```
HOME = /home/myproject
PATH = /home/myproject/bin:/home/myproject/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Those 2 lines added in crontab file did the trick.